# Why does sed not find the hostnames with this regex?

Tags: sed

The file contains lines like these:

```
1363650803.076     48 192.168.20.58 TCP_MISS/417 1963 POST http://collector-4.newrelic.com/agent_listener/invoke_raw_method? - NONE/- text/html
1363650863.426      0 192.168.20.58 TCP_MISS/417 1963 POST http://collector-4.newrelic.com/agent_listener/invoke_raw_method? - NONE/- text/html
1363650898.698  63995 192.168.20.61 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://65.55.122.235/2.0/blugro5relay.groove.microsoft.com/p9xyqk93z98qti59r7taftbcxe3s6rt52n4drjs,ConnType=LongLived,ContentLength=2147479552 - DIRECT/65.55.122.235 -
1363650898.698  63995 192.168.20.61 TCP_MISS/000 0 POST http://65.55.122.235/2.0/blugro5relay.groove.microsoft.com/p9xyqk93z98qti59r7taftbcxe3s6rt52n4drjs,ConnType=LongLived - DIRECT/65.55.122.235 -
1363650899.199  63991 192.168.20.61 TCP_MISS/000 0 GET http://65.55.122.235/2.0/blugro5relay.groove.microsoft.com/xatanmtq99upj97qtps89zqnx99wqsyeuc5yefa,ConnType=KeepAlive - DIRECT/65.55.122.235 -
1363650899.199  63991 192.168.20.61 TCP_MISS/000 0 POST http://65.55.122.235/2.0/blugro5relay.groove.microsoft.com/xatanmtq99upj97qtps89zqnx99wqsyeuc5yefa,ConnType=KeepAlive - DIRECT/65.55.122.235 -
```

I want to grab the host names/IP addresses from each line.

What is wrong with this sed command?

```
sed -rn "s@//([^/]+)/@\1@" access.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `-n` avoids printing each line. Remove it.

Second, Match the whole line and substitute all it with the content grouped.

Third, prepend `http:` just before `//` for a more accurate match.

It would be like:

```
sed -r "s@^.*http://([^/]+).*@\1@" infile
```

That yields:

```
collector-4.newrelic.com
collector-4.newrelic.com
65.55.122.235
65.55.122.235
65.55.122.235
65.55.122.235
```